# Filtering many to many field Django

Tags: sql, django, many-to-many, django-orm

I have a query like this:

```
    queryset = User.objects.filter(
            ~Q(pk=self.request.user.pk),
            ~Q(connections_as_initiator__peer=self.request.user, 
               connections_as_initiator__stopped=False))
```

Beetween one intitator and peer there could be numerous connections bun only one that is not `stopped`. So what I want this query to do is to find whether between the current user and the queried one there are active connections where the current user is a peer. But this is not what happens at all:

```
SELECT accounts_user.id FROM accounts_user
WHERE (
  NOT accounts_user.id = 48
  AND NOT accounts_user.id IN (SELECT U1.initiator_id AS col1 FROM connection U1 WHERE U1.peer_id = 48)
      AND NOT accounts_user.id IN (SELECT U1.initiator_id AS col1 FROM connection U1 WHERE U1.stopped = FALSE)
);
```

What I was thinking of (and what gives an expected result) is something like:

```
SELECT accounts_user.id FROM accounts_user
WHERE (
  NOT accounts_user.id = 48
  AND NOT accounts_user.id IN (SELECT U1.initiator_id AS col1 FROM connection U1 WHERE U1.peer_id = 48 AND U1.stopped = FALSE)
);
```

Is there a way to achieve that with ORM or should I start using raw SQL. I was also thinking about annotations, but I'm not yet 100% sure how to implement it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I came up with a solution.

```
queryset.annotate(
            initiated_conn_with_usr=Case(
                When(
                    connections_as_initiator__peer=self.request.user, 
                    connections_as_initiator__stopped=False, 
                    then=True
                ), default=False, output_field=models.BooleanField()
            )
        ).filter(initiated_conn_with_usr=True).distinct()
```

Which results in something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT accounts_user.id,
  CASE WHEN (connection.peer_id = 48 AND connection.stopped = false)
    THEN true ELSE false END AS initiated_conn_with_usr FROM accounts_user
  LEFT OUTER JOIN connection ON (accounts_user.id = connection.initiator_id)
WHERE (CASE WHEN (connection.peer_id = 48 AND connection.stopped = false)
  THEN true ELSE false END = false);
```

Possibly not the most optimal variant but at least it works in one request. Please let me know if there is a better way.